# Share Files on iOS between different Apps

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uipasteboard

I want to create a reusable class library for different apps on iOS let's call them:

- com.developer1.appname (App1)
- com.developer2.appname (App2)

My first goal is to let them share some data. 
App1 creates some data and saves the information. 
App2 loads the data and uses it for further processing.

I already read [ways to share on ios](https://medium.com/@dinesh.kachhot/different-ways-to-share-data-between-apps-de75a0a46d4a) and found somewhere that it could be possible to write my object data into images or contacts.

Right now, I'm facing the approach of the General Pasteboard.
However, after approx. one hour my object can not be found anymore in the pasteboard (altough it should be persistent [see](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard#1654138) )

Code for storing into the pasteboard:

```
partial void Testbutton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        var pasteboard = UIPasteboard.General;

        //Create Data
        // 4 * 1 MB
        IEnumerable<int> idata = Enumerable.Range(0, 1024);
        int[] iarray = idata.ToArray();
        byte[] data = new byte[1+iarray.Length * sizeof(int)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(iarray, 0, data, 1, data.Length-1);
        data[0] = counter++;

        NSData nsd = NSData.FromArray(data);

        // insert to pasteboard
        //pasteboard.SetData(nsd, "mydata");

        // nach etwa 1h ist es weg
        pasteboard.SetItemProviders(new NSItemProvider[] {new NSItemProvider(nsd, key)},false,NSDate.DistantFuture); 


        testlabel.Text = "Inserted Data to Pasteboard";
    }
```

code for reading item:

```
partial void Testbutton2_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        var pasteboard = UIPasteboard.General;
        bool contains = pasteboard.Contains(new[] { key });
        if(contains)
        {
            testlabel2.Text = $"Contains {key}";

            var data = pasteboard.DataForPasteboardType(key);
            var dataBytes = new byte[data.Length];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Bytes, dataBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(data.Length));

            int[] ints = new int[(dataBytes.Length-1)/4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(dataBytes, 1, ints, 0, dataBytes.Length - 1);
            testlabel.Text = "Loaded " + dataBytes.Length + " bytes";
            //testlabel2.Text += "Data = {"+dataBytes[0]+","+String.Join(", ", ints) +"}";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024 );
            sb.Append("Data = {" + dataBytes[0]);
            foreach (var i1 in ints)
            {
                sb.Append($", {i1.ToString()}");
            }
            testlabel2.Text = sb.ToString() + "}";
            int i = 123;
        }
        else
        {
            testlabel2.Text = $"Contains NOT {key}";
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me what why the object is beeing deleted in this case, or what would be a nice way to share objects (typically bytearrays) between two apps from different developers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pasteboard is for the user to control not an app. If the user selects Copy and Paste that's fine but the app should not do it without user interaction

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what approach would you suggest to share files properly between different apps (from different developers/teams).
CustomURLscheme might work but then App2 asks for data and App1 gets to foreground. After that App1 has to call an URL for App2 to get App2 back into foreground.